# Build error as soon as I enable dataBinding for Android Library Project

Tags: android, data-binding, android-library

I am getting a build error as soon as I enable dataBinding for my library project:

AAPT: No resource type specified (at 'text' with value '@{user.name}')

If I enable **dataBinding** for the  **application** module, it works **fine**.
But if I enable dataBinding for my **lib** project, I get the above **error**.

### build.gradle of application module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

dataBinding{
    enabled true
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xyz.databindingtrial"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
  compile project(path: ':librarytrial')
}
```

### build.gradle of lib project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

dataBinding{
    enabled true
}

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

The layout file:

```
<data class="UserTrackingBinding">

    <variable
        name="user"
        type="xyz.databindingtrial.model.User"/>
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="xyz.databindingtrial.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{user.name}"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

### The activity code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  UserTrackingBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
  User user = new User("Test");
  binding.setUser(user);
```

}

### User Model

```
public class User extends BaseObservable {
 private final String name;
 public User(String name){
 this.name = name;
 }
 @Bindable
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }
}
```

## Does dataBinding not work with library projects? If it does, what is wrong with my setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work with library projects but any app that depends on a library that uses data binding has to enable data binding even if they don't use it.

Comment: if you enabled it in both, it should work. If not, can you file a bug report with a project?
FYI we do have a test project in the automated tests that tests both a separate library and a project with 2 modules but there can always be edge cases so an app to reproduce would help. (or maybe i can see the error there)

Comment: You need `dataBinding.enabled = true` not `dataBinding.enabled true`

Comment: @yigit - Figured out the issue. The package structure messed up things for me. The package structure in the manifest and the actual package structure was different. Reason being we are dealing with legacy codebase and it got overlooked. It is working fine. Thanks for the links.

Comment: Actually 'dataBinding.enabled = true' didn't worked for me. I needed to 
'dataBinding { enabled = true}'

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue. The package structure messed up things for me. The package structure in the manifest and the actual package structure was different. Reason being we are dealing with legacy codebase and it got overlooked. It is working fine.

Comment: Wow thank you. My lib manifest ended up with the same package as my app because I was not using Android Studio's renaming refactoring correctly. Remarkably subtle bug, the app would crash with `IllegalStateException: DataBindingUtil.inflate(…youtId, container, false) must not be null` when it tried to create a fragment. Hopefully it helps future googlers :)